# Android Studio Cannot Recover Key

Tags: android, android-studio, build, recover

I changed the Android studio version from 2.1.1 to 3.4.1. I have a game on Playstore. I updated my game after I changed the Android Studio 3.4.1 version. However, I'm having an error recovering my key while making a signed apk. This error is "Cannot recover key".

My storepass and keypass are the same. I copied and pasted all of the values from cmd to android studio.

I have researched this error on this site. I have tried almost everything but I still get this error.

Any ideas? What should I do?